# command button creation with vba

Tags: vba

What is the vba code to add a command button on currentworksheet, then insert a code to run whenever that button is clicked?

advance thanks. Note: the task for the command button click is : select workbook name "123"(which is already opend), select worksheet name "ABC" then select range a123.

Answer (score 0):

Typical button maker:

```
Sub button_maker()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(94.5, 75.75, 51, 27.75).Select
        Selection.OnAction = "macro123"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select
        Selection.Characters.Text = "macro123"
    r.Select
End Sub
```

and typical button code:

```
Sub macro123()
    Workbooks("123.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("ABC").Select
    Range("A123").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply....but I want the task should done by command click it self....not through a macro.waiting for valuable reply.